# Computer program for visualizing multivariable Calculus topics

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am an undergraduate studying multivariable Calculus. However I have difficulty visualizing concepts. In single variable calculus I can visualize stuff, for example when one talks about derivatives, I can see the tangent line etc. In multivariable, I can prove that gradient is perpendicular to the level curves, but If I have a graph of a function, I can't visualize gradient in every single point.
Is there a computer program for this issue? Do I have to learn something like Mathematica or are there another options?

Comment: This question is not appropriate for this site, but I would, in fact, suggest "learning something like Mathematica", since this will serve you in good stead for years to come.

Comment: I could imagine an improved version of this question at http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/